# How to connect to another laptop

Tags: linux, networking

Now I have two laptops (not necessary in one local network). I want to install client program on the first laptop and daemon program on the second one.

How to make one laptop be visible and accessible to another one over the network (maybe by `IP`, `port` and `certificate`)?

Comment: Which operating system ist are you using is it linux (saw the word demion in there) and do you want to access files only or desktop or services running on other machine eg printer

Comment: @arthurkamande both linux machines. I want to access services like docker daemon.

Comment: Are the systems connected to any network? You say "not necessarily in one local network", but do they have networking up and running at all? Can you browse the Internet from both?

Comment: Yes, they both have an access to the internet.

Comment: Check this link about it pertains to docker dameon https://sheerun.net/2014/05/17/remote-access-to-docker-with-tls/

Comment: VPN? Wireless? One access to the other? `sshd` `ssh`? Ask google `Remote desktop software list`? A [list from wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software)? teamviewer? TightVNC, mx...?

Comment: @arthurkamande problem is how can I make second laptop be visible to first one by IP address.

Comment: To know the public IP you can, among the other ways, use `curl ipinfo.io/ip`, or `curl ident.me` or  `wget -qO- http://ipecho.net/plain ; echo` or ... check for example [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/95910/196535). Then maybe you have to reroute some port of the router to the laptop... You can use even some service as noip... (http://www.noip.com/)

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add some specification more... now it imply a wide range of configuration and solution... and someone could ask to close the question. Try to write your needs (laptop on the same but sometime even not on the same network...etc etc), direct wireless connection, normally connected to router(s) that I can/cannot set-up... BTW a VPN can be the all-round solution. Good Luck.